# Route [add.sp] not defined

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

i wrote url like that

```
use App\Http\Controllers\DashController;
Route::get('/admin/special', [DashController::class, 'addSpecializations'])->name('add.sp');
```

this is controller

```
public function addSpecializations()
{
    return view('dashboard.add-specializations');
}
```

when i tried to open it i can't even though all route work

after that i wrote this code in view's file

```
<a href="{{route('add.sp')}}">
```

so i faced this issue

> Route [add.sp] not defined.

Comment: Run `php artisan route:clear` and try again. If you have your routes cached it won't pick it up. Your code looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

In case your routes are cached, run `php artisan route:clear`. In development, don't cache anything, including views and config.